# status code: 401, reason phrase: Unauthorized using Azure Devops API

Tags: groovy, azure-devops, jira, scriptrunner-for-jira

I am actually trying to call some Azure devops API using Basic Authentication and Personal Token.
This inside groovy script in Jira script runner

based on official documentation is is mentionned that the token need to be converted to Base64 as explain in the following link :
[Pwrsonal Token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=Windows#use-a-pat)

Then in my groovy script I encode my token as below :

```
String _AuthToken     ="itecor:[my personnal token]".bytes.encodeBase64().toString()
```

Then in my API call I pass the Token to the header as below :

```
 def http = new HTTPBuilder(graph_base_Url)
        
            http.request(POST) {

                requestContentType = ContentType.JSON
                body=[
                       definitionId: _definitionId,
                       variables: [ InstanceNum: _instanceNb,
                                    Version: _version
                       ]
                      ]
  

               headers.'Authorization' = "Basic ${_AuthToken}"
                response.success = { resp, json ->
                     _jobInfo=json.toString()
                }
```

Then when executing my code, I get the error : "status code: 401, reason phrase: Unauthorized"

Any idea what I am doing wrong ?

Regards

Comment: Where does the "itecor" come from for the username part in the Basic Authentication header? In the documentation you shared it actually looks like the username part is empty. So, maybe just try with `_AuthToken = ":[PAT]".bytes...`?

Comment: Issue is solves it was comminf from a corrupted paersonnal token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has been solved. Error was coming from a corrupted token